# Windows FFMPEG will not find my files at all

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I have a folder full of images that go from 0 to whatever number, and I need to turn these images to a video. They are all .PNG files. Here is my command I am using:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -framerate 30 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 1 -r 30 -i "img%%04d.jpg" -s 1280x720 test.avi
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
[image2 @ 002be580] Could find no file with path 'img%04d.jpg' and index in the range 1-5

img%04d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

What can I change to get this to work?

Comment: does this work? img%%%%04d.jpg

Comment: @AndreyVolk, I still get the same error. I took a screenshot if that helps. http://i.imgur.com/qWQnrTI.png

Comment: rename your file and try again

Comment: What is the actual name of one of your typical input files?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, img0.png The number keeps going up by one each frame.

Answer (score 4):

## sequence pattern

The default pattern type. `img%d.jpg` will expect `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`, etc. Using `img%04d.jpg` will expect `img0001.jpg`, `img0002.jpg`, etc.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%d.jpg -vf scale=1280:-1,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

## glob pattern

A glob wildcard pattern type is flexible. This pattern type is available if libavformat was compiled with globbing support.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -vf scale=1280:-1,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

### Notes

- See the [FFmpeg image2 demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more info.
- The [`scale` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) in this example will change the width to 1280 and the height will be automatically calculated to preserve the aspect.
- Depending on your version, input type (such as PNG), encoder (libx264 specifically), and encoding options, `ffmpeg` may attempt to avoid or minimize chroma subsampling, but most non-FFmpeg based players will be unable to properly decode the output. The [`format` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) will ensure the output uses a chroma subsampling scheme that is compatible with these players.

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me running the cmd in the same directory making:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i Animation%3d.jpg -r 5 -y fileout.mp4
```

For files named Animation000 to 999.jpg.

This hasn't worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

It generated the error:

> Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not supported by this libavformat build *.jpg: Function not implemented